# Passing "array of pointers" to function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a top function with an array of pointers like this:

```
Membership *mf[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    mf[i]=(Membership*) malloc(sizeof(Membership))
```

where `Membership` is a structure. 
So far so good and when debugging, `mf` shows all the 5 entities correctly. Problem is when I pass that array of pointers to a function (which can't have anything to do with pointers) like this:

```
call_function(*mf)
```

where `call_function()` is declared like this:

```
void call_function(Membership mf[5]){
    normalize_function(mf[0],slope);
    ....
    normalize_function(mf[5],fuel);
}
```

In there, `mf`just becomes useless and with length 1 instead of 5. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong, even after searching/reading about this and debugging for a while. Please help me on how to change `call_function()` (not the array of pointers).

Edit: As suggested I did some changes to the code.

Edit2: In response to KyleStrand's answer: `call_function()`can't have anything to do with pointers because that function is actually going to be implemented in FPGA (VHDL coding) and pointers there are unecessary complications.

Comment: Don't dereference mf when you call,i.e. call_function (..., mf) instead.

Comment: @caveman That doesn't work

Comment: Shouldn't that declaration be `void call_function(...,Membership[5]);`, i.e., shouldn't it expect an array of type `Membership` (since `mf` is not a type)?

Comment: @JoãoPereira What doesn't work?

Comment: @JoãoPereira show the actual code, I sense someting fishy here.

Comment: Membership mf[5] ? 5 is actually omitted and is treated exactly the same as Membership* mf. So it has very much everything to do with pointers.

Comment: @KyleStrand Yes, that was a typo, ty for the attention. About the doesn''t work: if I don't dereference the problem is the same

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating individual `Memberships` instead of just allocating the array all at once: `Membership *mf = malloc(sizeof(*mf) * 5);`?

Comment: @AustinMullins You are correct, I could easily do what u said. But that does not solve the problem

Comment: Can you edit the question to reflect the comments and answers already offered? We appear to be missing something critical to understanding your problem.

Comment: Just wanted to say that arrays are syntactic sugar for pointers to memory address. So when OP is saying that function can have nothing to do with pointers and yet is passing an array to the function, this leads to a contradiction

Comment: A "pointer to the first element in a contiguous array of 5 Memberships" (a.k.a `Membership mf[5]`) is not directly convertible to "pointer to the first element in a contiguous array of 5 pointers, each of which point to a single Membership" (a.k.a `Membership *mf[5]`), or vice versa.

Comment: @twalberg @Smac89 Well, that's what I was thinking could be the problem. So your advice is to change the code in the top function to have `Membership mf[5]`and not `Membership *mf[5]` right?

Comment: What exactly is implemented in VHDL here? `call_function`, as shown, is a C function. Are you saying `normalize_function` is implemented in VHDL? If so, that has no bearing on how to declare, implement, or call `call_function`. Note that calling `normalize_function(mf[n]...)` calls `normalize_function` with the `n`th element of `mf`, thus *dereferencing* the pointer `mf`--so in that case you *would* be using pointers inside `call_function`, but you would *not* be passing pointers to `normalize_function`. This appears to be what you want.

Comment: No, `call_function`is going to be implemented in VHDL, i.e. the code from C corresponding to `call_function()`is going to be "automatically" translated to VHDL via Vivado HLS.

Comment: I hope you are not saying what I wrote, because that means you are still contradicting yourself, but the other thing you said makes sense. Change the array you are passing to the function to `Membership mf[5]` and remove the for loop because this is no longer an array of pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say that `call_function` "can't have anything to do with pointers", it's unclear what you mean. It appears that the function's last parameter is an *array of `Membership`s*, and in fact an array is treated very much like a pointer in C. When you pass `*mf` to the function, you are *dereferencing* the array, which is to say, you are *accessing the first member of the array*. This is not what you want, since `call_function` takes an *array* rather than an *array member*. @caveman's comment is correct: you should pass the *raw array* (i.e. without dereferencing it).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some type issues.  This is the sort of format you should have.  It's a community wiki, so others can clean up and improve.

```
void call_function (Membership* local_mf[5])
{
    Membership* m = local_mf[0];
}

int main (void)
{
   Membership* mf[5];
   ... // malloc, etc, etc.
   call_function (mf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question, it is unclear from your question what you would like to do.

But

```
Membership *mf[5]
```

is a an array whose elements are pointers of type Membership

if you pass `mf` to a function, then you are passing an array as an argument to a function and `mf` itself is treated as a pointer. It points to the first element of its members. So in this case `mf` becomes a pointer to the first Membership pointer in its elements.

so inside the function (outside the function as well):

```
*mf would give you a pointer of type Membership (the first pointer)

*(mf+1) would give you a pointer of type Membersip (the second element)

**mf would give you an element of type membership (the element which the first pointer evaluates to).
```

you cannot get the length of `mf` or any array inside a function, because if you pass an array as an argument, it is treated like a pointer inside the function, so if you do something like:

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(first_element)
```

`sizeof(array)` inside the function will always equal to the size of a pointer, which will be 4 or 8 bytes depending on your system.

so if you are using `sizeof(mf)/sizeof(Membership*)` to get the length of `mf` inside your function, that just means `8/8` or `4/4` which will always equal 1.